# How do i activate or install suphp on my dedicated apache server?

Tags: apache-2.2, suphp

i want to install suphp on my dedicated server, maybe it´s already installed and not activated but i don´t know hot to check for that.
Can someone please tell me how to install and/or activate it.

Thanks!

Server Version: Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.2.9

Comment: OS? Package manager? And keep in mind fastcgi + suxec is equally viable.

Answer (score 0):

List of loaded modules:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Or:

```
apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Normal enablement of a module:

```
a2enmod <modulename>
```

Figuring out wether a module is there but inactive: depends on your OS / packages. For instance, in Debian / 'Buntu flavors there's a list in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`, or you can search for installed package related to apache with `dpkg -l '*apache*'`
.